# Varieties with parameters

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, affine-varieties, projective-varieties, deformation-theory

This seems like a very basic question to me and I am certain that people studied it a lot. It is for sure related to deformation theory and families of varieties, but I am not sure how these fields would answer it (and I know very little of them).

Say, we are given polynomials $f_{1,(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(x_1,\ldots,x_d),\ldots,f_{m,(a_1,\ldots,a_n)}(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ (can be assumed to be homogeneous) over a field $k$ (algebraically closed, if you want), in the variables $x_i$ and with parameters $a_j \in k$. So, changing the parameters changes the polynomials and therefore the variety $V_{\underline a}$ they define.

**Q1:** Is it possible to describe the set $A$ of all points $\underline a$ such that

1. $V_{\underline a}$ is smooth,
2. $V_{\underline a}$ is irreducible,
3. $V_{\underline a}$ is contained in some given variety $W$,
4. an irreducible component of $V_{\underline a}$ is contained in $W$,
5. $V_{\underline a}$ contains a given point,
6. $V_{\underline a}$ satisfies some other interesting property?

**Q2:** Is such a set $A$ usually a variety itself? If yes, how does one extract its equations from the equations of $V$?

It would be very helpful for me if you could propose to me a good reference for such questions, especially with a view into the direction of applications to explicit families of varieties, e.g., defined by two quadratic equations, each in four parameters, where the parameter sets are disjoint, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your polynomials are functions of the parameters $a_1,\dots,a_n$, so in particular their coefficients are functions of these parameters. Are the coefficients rational functions in the parameters? Without information about this I don't think one can answer your question in full generality.

Comment: I would even say that the coefficients are monomials in the parameters.

Comment: In that case all the properties you mention will define a constructible set. A constructible set is a finite union of locally closed sets (it is a set that can be be formed from closed subvarieties by iterating intersections, unions, and taking complements). See EGA, IV.3.9 (there does not seem to be a stacks project entry). A key point here is that the image of a constructible set under a morphism of finite type between noetherian schemes is constructible. This is a theorem of Chevalley but is also equivalent to elimination of quantifiers in the theory of algebraically closed fields.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by EGA IV.3.9? Chapter IV of EGA only goes up to 3.4.

Comment: Sorry I mean EGA IV.9 (which is in the third part of chap. IV).